# Carter Constant with a Cosmological Constant

Tags: general-relativity, kerr-metric, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime, kerr-newman-metric

The Carter constant for the [Kerr Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kerr-Newman-Orbit-1.gif#Equations) metric

$$ \rm C = p_{\theta}^{2} + \cos^{2}\theta \ \Bigg[ a^2 \ (m^2 - E^2) + \left(\frac{L_z}{\sin\theta} \right)^{2} \Bigg] $$

with (in $[+---]$ signature)

$${{\rm E = -p_t}=g_{\rm tt} \ {\rm \dot{t}}+g_{\rm t \phi} \ {\rm \dot{\phi}} + \rm q \ A_{t}}$$

$${\rm L_z = p_{\phi}}=-g_{\rm \phi \phi} \ {\rm \dot{\phi}}-g_{\rm t \phi} \ {\rm \dot{t}} - \rm q \ A_{\phi}$$

$${\rm p_{\theta}}=-g_{\rm \theta\theta} \ {\rm \dot{\theta} \ } { \color{#aaaaaa}{ - \ g_{\rm t \theta} \ {\rm \dot{t}} - \rm q \ A_{\theta}}}$$

(with the terms that are 0 grayed out) does not work in the [Kerr Newman (Anti) De Sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman%E2%80%93de%E2%80%93Sitter_metric#Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates) metric. In some references on the subject I've seen it mentioned though, but I've never seen its explicit form in any of them. Does it even exist in this case?

I suspect if so, there must be some additional terms dependend on $\Lambda$ and $\theta$, since even on an orbit at constant $\rm r$ (but variable $\theta$) the form that works fine with $\Lambda=0$ gives a sine-like function with $\Lambda \neq 0$ (with an orbit like [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_in_the_Kerr_Newman_De_Sitter_Spacetime.png) where the other constants of motion $\rm E$ and $\rm L_z$ work just fine and stay constant as they should).

Since Carter seems to have come up with his constant with a lucky guess while no one really knows why it even works, I'm not sure how to derive it by first principles, and before I try to land a lucky guess myself, maybe somebody has already figured it out or knows a reference where it is not only mentioned, but also given (for the KNdS/KNAdS metric).

It doesn't really matter since I use the second order equations of motion anyway, and the two constants of motion $\rm E$ and $\rm L_z$ are sufficient to monitor the numerical stability, but for the sake of completeness I'm still interested if there is a version of the Carter constant that works with $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.0409.pdf) is a paper that gives the Conformal Killing-Yano tensor for any member of the Plebanski–Demianski family of solutions. This is the most general family of type D vacuum solutions to the Einstein-Maxwell equation with cosmological constant, which includes the Kerr-Newman-(Anti-)deSitter solutions.

For members of this family without acceleration (e.g. KNAdS), this becomes a regular Killing-Yano tensor. The Carter constant is found by contracting the Killing-Yano tensor with the 4-momentum, and then taking the norm.

Comment: +1 since it is at least a reference, but to accept I must first work out if it works, which might take a while since they don't give an explicit form and use unfamiliar coordinates instead of using gμν, so that might take a while. I suspect you mean equation (17), where they say *"which generates the
Carter’s constant for a geodesic motion"* (since the Carter constant for the regular Kerr Newman metric in my question works for charged particles which travel under the influence of a force and therefore are not geodesic I suspect they don't really limit their constant to geodesics, or do they?

Comment: In order to work for electric/magnetically charged particles. The Killing tensor $K_{ab}$ also needs to satisfy $K_{a(b}F_{c)}^d$ and $K_{a(b}{\star}F_{c)}^d$. The paper does not check whether that is true. It is however, true in the Kerr-Newman limit, so it's worth checking.

Comment: [This reference](https://inspirehep.net/files/6da87a5f417fff37ac453bce85140874#page=48) seems a little bit more explicit, I'll test what works under which conditions and give an update when I'm done